# How do I achieve navigation without affecting browser history?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, navigation

If you go here: http://twitter.com/account/resend_password

Then click on "Send Instructions" without filling in the form, it appears to be doing a full, non-ajax request.

However, if I look at my browser history, the previous page (resend_password) isn't in the history. It's as if it made an ajax request.

What is twitter doing? Is this really just an ajax request, or is it doing something tricky?

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.replace` will load a page but won't save it in the history.

```
window.location.replace('http://twitter.com/account/resend_password');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ajax request.

It is not something tricky either.

Twitter is only answering the HTTP POST request with an HTTP response code number 302 (Moved Temporarily) - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection. The browser answers as if it was an HTTP response code number 303 (See Other).

In fact, what happens is merely a **redirection to the same page**.

---

**Edit**: added code for testing purposes.

I have just tested with the following code, and it confirms what is said above:

```
<form method="post"><input type="submit" value="click here" /></form>
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
    header( 'Location: /test.php', true, 302 );
?>
```

I am using PHP as the server-side language. I saved this script as `test.php` in the webserver public root folder. It behaves exactly as the Twitter page: clicking the form submit button, the **302 redirection** is triggered by using the `header` function. The browser history does not change.

Comment: I think it's something more. When I replicate redirection to the same page, the browser history advances.

Comment: @Brian: I had not performed any testing when I first posted my answer. Now, I have tested, and it worked. Are you sure you sent HTTP response code 302 from server-side to the browser in your redirection?

Comment: You should do a Google research for "redirection after form processing" or something similar (http://www.google.com/search?q=redirection+after+form+processing). The intention behind the technique is to avoid the submission of the same data for a second time... see http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/get-redirect-after-post or http://raventools.com/blog/redirect-after-form-processing/ ... and there are many others.